# Firebase security, only auth/admin can delete?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I must be missing something obvious?
How do I setup firebase security rules so:

1. any user can ONLY read and create new data
2. admin/auth can ALSO delete the data

I can't see anywhere in the documentation the ability to have multiple `".write"` rules for the same directory...

```
    {
     "rules": {
        ".read": true,

        // this only occurs if "auth === null" otherwise should be full access.
        ".write": "!data.exists() && newData.exists()"
      }
    }
```